# Snap: Getting form data and the "if"

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I dont seem to be able to understand how to get the form data with heist.
I just started looking into Haskell web frameworks but documentation is a bit ... scarce, to say the least. There is no mention of forms in the skinny heist tutorial on the snap website.
So given a simple html form, how do I get the form data for processing into my handler function? Can anyone point me to a tutorial, google just keeps quiet on this one? Or maybe a short example ...

Also, where do I get information on the conditional control? Say, if I want conditionally include certain parts of the html within my page, how do I do it with heist? Basically, where is the "if"?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried getQueryParams for GETs or getPostParams for POSTs, from [Snap.Core](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap-core/0.8.0/doc/html/Snap-Core.html) ? I have not used them but they seem to do what you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Using digestive functors with Heist](http://norm2782.github.com/blog/2012/01/01/using-digestive-functors-with-heist/) for a good tutorial on simple forms, and [mightybyte's musings](http://softwaresimply.blogspot.com/search/label/heist) about heist.  If you're planning on using `multipart/form-data` use the `Snap.Util.FileUploads` module.

You could use a `Splice` to generate content based on a condition.
A `Splice` returns a list of `Node`'s,

```
mySplice = do
  -- get environment conditions
  -- condition could be passed in as a parameter 
  if condition 
     then return [] -- do nothing
     else return [TextNode "some content"] -- see Text.XmlHtml
```

You would then bind this splice to a tag using something like:

`bindSplice myTag mysplice defaultHeistState`

And place `<myTag/>` in your template. When `Heist` renders the template, it will evaluate the splice when it encounters the tag and insert the value in its place.

Comment: Thanks for the "if" example. I'll try to digest this. Also, thank you for the tutorial link, although it does not explain what I need. I dont want to generate a form or do anything fancy. I just want to write a form using just HTML and stick it in heist template. Given a simple <INPUT> tag and submit, what function do I use from within the action handler to grab the form data? What can possibly be simpler? :) Thanks.

Comment: @r.sendecky In that case you would just use `getParam` or `getPostParam` as mentioned above by Paul.

Comment: Thank you. That should do it. I was confused about the function getParams because I thought it is used to extract the URL variable. Apparently it does both. I dont understand yet how it works but I will test it.